# Propel: Getting query results from 2 db tables even when second table has no corresponding entries

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, propel

My Problem: Getting query results from 2 db tables with PROPEL2 even when second table has no corresponding entries. If the second has corresponding entries than it is no problem.

I have 3 tables: Entry, Contingent and Favorit.
The schema is as follow:

Entry.id [PK] 
Entry.contingent_id [FK] 
Entry.expert_id

Contingent.id [PK] 
Contingent.name

Favorit.id [PK] 
Favorit.contingent_id [FK] 
Favorit.expert_id
Favorit.pos

I want to get for a specified expert_id ($id) all entries from Entry with contingent-name and if exists the favorit.pos for this expert and contingent. I get the wanted with:

```
$result = EntryQuery::create()
->filterByExpertId($id)
->join('Entry.Contingent')
->withColumn('Contingent.name','_contingentName')
->join('Contingent.Favorit')
->where('Favorit.expert_id = ?', $id)
->find();
```

This works only if there exists such a favorit.pos . In some cases this element doesn’t exists (what is wanted from the system). In these cases I want to get the result too just with favorit.pos as empty, null or 0. But Propel doesn’t return me these records.

With MySQL I have no problem to get the desired result:

```
SELECT entry.* ,
    (SELECT favorit.position
     FROM contingent, favorit
     WHERE
        favorit.expert_id = entry.expert_id
        AND entry.contingent_id = contingent.id
        AND contingent.id = favorit.contingent_id
    )
FROM `entry`
JOIN contingent
ON  entry.contingent_id = contingent.id
WHERE
    entry.expert_id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Join left in code:

```
->join('Contingent.Favorit','selection conditon','left' )
```

This left work when empty database when condition is false
in condition like `'id'=$id`